# Drop content close in mouseleave

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

This is my menu http://jsfiddle.net/qj5hN/

Problem about mouseleave function. When hover on a menu element it opens a new content below. And if you carry the cursor slowly on new drop content suddenly it close. I don't know how. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 71 in the css, change the padding on the active menu element to 12 px instead of 11. There is a 1 pixel gap in the original.

http://jsfiddle.net/qj5hN/2/